# PriorityQueue and LinkedList Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I need to use different data structures depending on a strategy and I have a class called Fringe which represents where I store the data. Fringe extends LinkedList, which allows me to use it both as a queue and as a stack. However, for another strategy, I need to use PriorityQueue and I am not sure how to I can do it using the same Fringe class. I am not sure which would be the most elegant solution for this. Obviously, I could use some if statements to solve this problem, but I was thinking if I could do something more elegant, using polymorphism. I want in my "solve" method to only use a Fringe, without the data structures appearing explicitly.

Comment: Both LinkedList and PriorityQueue implement the java.util.Queue interface. Conceptually, a queue is very similar to a list, no random access but you add to the end of it. So you should be able to keep your fringe class and at least override the "add" method. Based on the strategy, you would need to do the right thing in the add method. i.e. invoke add in LinkedList vs PriorityQueue.

Comment: But by implementing the Queue I have to write implementations for all the methods of the Queue. Now I am only extending LinkedList, so I don't have to provide implementations for all the methods.

Comment: I can't see how you could accomodate for all required data structures by extending  one base class. asking on strategy and maintaining a reference to chosen data structure seems like a passable solution

Comment: You said Fringe extends LinkedList. That mans you already have the Queue interface implemented in the parent class. But you would need to override them as at the moment they are List implementation only. As @SharonBenAsher said, there is no way to accomodate for all the data structures by extending one base class. Java does not support multiple inheritance of classes.

Comment: I see. Thank you!